# Правильное взаимодействие модулей

Tags: python, gui, импорт

У меня исключительно теоретический вопрос, я не прошу писать фрагменты кода, а всего лишь насколько это возможно подробный ответ на следующий вопрос:
Если есть основной модуль, где выполняются различные сложные вычисления, анализ данных и их обработка, а отдельно от него создан модуль с `GUI`. Запускается основной поток с `GUI` посредством создания экземпляра его класса в модуле с вычислениями, то есть, как вы уже догадались, в модуле есть строка `from GUI import classGui`. Но в модуле с интерфейсом есть кнопки, которые должны вызывать функции из модуля, в котором импортирован `gui`. А как все знают, циклический импорт запрещен. Как можно обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Вкратце - использовать инверсию зависимостей. Модуль с вычислениями ничего не должен знать о модуле графического интерфейса, а знать только о каком-то абстрактном классе/интерфейсе, реализация которого ему будет доступна, чтобы взаимодействовать с остальным миром.

Comment: По-хорошему, наверное, всё же модуль с `GUI` должен быть основным и из него должно всё запускаться и вызываться.

Comment: Доступно, спасибо за информацию